# Developing lambda expression

Tags: kotlin

```
var t = 0
fun sumIntMap(hm: HashMap<Int,Int>) = hm.forEach{ x -> t+=x.value 
}.let { t }
```

Trying to sum a Hashmap Int values here with a function, I cannot seem to optimize it so that it requires not capturing and needing the temp var (t).

How can I use temp vars in lambdas and return them? Is how I wrote it the only real way (using a let to return the temp var)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can map your `HashMap` entries to their values to get a List of Ints, and then sum the values in that list:

```
hm.map { it.value }.sum()
```

If you have a `List` instead of a `Map`, you can also use [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) or [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) to do similar things to your original code:

```
hm.toList().fold(0, { acc, pair -> acc + pair.second })
```

Comment: Hi there, really I was looking at the general concept of returning a specific value from a lambda when the lambda handles multiple vars (in this case x & t) using let allows me to do this but can it be done within the lambda itself without chaining?

Comment: @HiLo, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but maybe you're looking for [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html), which is really a more general `sum`.

Comment: You'll either have to chain calls or use an operator like `fold` or `reduce` - those are only available on a `List` though, not a `Map`.

I've edited my answer with a solution using `fold` which looks more like your code, that operator might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I believe you could even destructure `pair` into `(_, value)`, perhaps this fits with Kotlin's functional features :)

Comment: @HiLo the concept you are talking about is `fold`. Read the second part of @zsmb13 's answer, he's right. The 0 replaces your t = 0 and acc is effectively your t. Also note that you can just do 'hm.values' to get the values: `hm.values.fold(0)  { t, v -> t + v}`